# How to display data in a simple grid in extjs

Tags: javascript, eclipse, extjs, extjs4

Why is the output not displayed in the browser?

I have all Eclipse settings, and I am using Chrome.

```
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript" >

    Ext.onReady(function(){ 

    var store = new Ext.data.Store({  data: [ [ 1, "Office Space", "Mike Judge", "1999-02-19", 1, "Work Sucks", "19.95", 1  ],

    [3, "Super Troopers", "Jay Chandrasekhar", "2002-02-15",  1, "Altered State Police",  "14.95", 1  ] ],

    reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader({id:'id'}, [ 'id', 'title', 'director', {name: 'released', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'}, 'genre', 'tagline', 'price',    'available'  ] });


    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({  renderTo: document.body, frame:true, title: 'Movie Database',  height:200, width:500,  store: store, 
    columns: [ {header: "Title", dataIndex: 'title'},        
     {header: "Director", dataIndex: 'director'},        
     {header: "Released", dataIndex: 'released',
     renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y')},
     {header: "Genre", dataIndex: 'genre'},  
     {header: "Tagline", dataIndex: 'tagline'} ] });    
    </script>     
   </head>
   <body>     
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you post any code then please make it proper formatted to clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If I run your exact code, I get the error `TypeError: me.model is undefined` in the debugger console.  What this error is hinting at is that you do not have a model, or fields, defined for your store (more on that later).  So the first thing you'll want to do is use some sort of browser debugger (`ctrl-shift-i` for Firefox/Chrome on Windows).

Secondly, if you're using Ext JS 4, then you'll want to use an [`ArrayStore`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.ArrayStore)--newer versions of the framework automatically deduce how to organize the data in the store, so this step isn't necessary if you're using v5+.  The reason we're using this special type of store is because of how your data is organized... into arrays.

The final thing you'll want to do is set up either a [Model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) for your store, or the [fields](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field) that your data makes up... you currently have these fields in the reader, but it doesn't make much sense to have them there.  Also, a [reader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader) goes inside of a proxy, and you usually don't have to do much with the reader itself.

Here's a working [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/vlk):

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
      data: [
        [1, "Office Space", "Mike Judge", "1999-02-19", 1, "Work Sucks", "19.95", 1],

        [3, "Super Troopers", "Jay Chandrasekhar", "2002-02-15", 1, "Altered State Police", "14.95", 1]
      ],
      fields: [{
          name: 'id',
          type: 'int'
        }, {
          name: 'title',
          type: 'string'
        }, {
          name: 'director',
          type: 'string'
        }, {
          name: 'released',
          type: 'date',
          dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
        }, {
          name: 'genre',
          type: 'int'
        }, {
          name: 'tagline',
          type: 'string'
        }, {
          name: 'price',
          type: 'string'
        }, {
          name: 'available',
          type: 'int'
        }]
        //reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader({id:'id'}, [ 'id', 'title', 'director', {name: 'released', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'}, 'genre', 'tagline', 'price',    'available'  ])
    });


    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
      renderTo: document.body,
      frame: true,
      title: 'Movie Database',
      height: 200,
      width: 500,
      store: store,
      columns: [{
        header: "Title",
        dataIndex: 'title'
      }, {
        header: "Director",
        dataIndex: 'director'
      }, {
        header: "Released",
        dataIndex: 'released',
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y')
      }, {
        header: "Genre",
        dataIndex: 'genre'
      }, {
        header: "Tagline",
        dataIndex: 'tagline'
      }]
    });
  }
});
```